# Vector calculus for ellipse in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I'm having trouble with this question, can somebody please help me with it! I'll thanks/like your comment if help me =)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGKhm.png]

I know that for a ellipse the parametric is $x=a\sin t$ , $b= b \cos t$, $t\in (0, 2\pi)$ (?)

For part a) I drew up the graph but not sure if it's right. The circle has radius 1 and for the ellipse I'm able to find $x= 2 $.
$$
(x-1)^2 =9  \\
\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=\sqrt 9\\
x-1=3\\
x=4$$

For $y=2\sqrt 2$
$$
y^2=8\\
\sqrt y=\sqrt 8\\
y=\sqrt 4 \sqrt 2\\
y= 2\sqrt 2 \text{ or } 2.8 $$

So the region should be the circle? since the ellipse covers the whole circle?
Thank you very much for helping! 
Cheers.

Comment: How would I go about finding the boundary conditions for question 3?

Answer (score 2):

I am noting you a useful Theorem which I found it for you. So by using it you can defeat the second part of your question by yourself.

> Theorem: The proper conic with focus-directrix distance $p$ and eccentricity $e$ has equation $$r=\frac{ep}{1-e\cos \theta}$$ in polar coordinates, if the focus is at the pole and the polar axis is perpendicular to the directrix $L$ in the direction pointing away from $l$. (Fig below)

[image]

Additional points here are $e=\frac{c}a<1,p=\frac{a^2}{c}-c$ where your ellipse is $$x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$$ Here we have $a=3,b=\sqrt{8}$ so $$c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=1,~~e=\frac{1}3,~~p=\frac{9}{1}-1=8$$ Now put these to the formula in the theorem. This solves the second part.

Comment: useful indeed, and illustrated, too!

Comment: @BabakS.: +1 for going the extra mile! +1

Comment: c)

R is region outside circle: r = 1 
and inside ellipse: r = 8/(3−cosθ)

Limits: 
1 ≤ r ≤ 8/(3−cosθ)
0 ≤ θ ≤ 2π

ƒ = 1/(x²+y²)^(3/2) = 1/(r²)^(3/2) = 1/r³

∫∫ ƒ dA = ∫ [0 to 2π] ∫ [1 to 8/(3−cosθ)] 1/r³ * r dr dθ
R
. . . . . = ∫ [0 to 2π] ∫ [1 to 8/(3−cosθ)] 1/r² dr dθ
. . . . . = ∫ [0 to 2π] (−1/r) | [1 to 8/(3−cosθ)] dθ
. . . . . = ∫ [0 to 2π] (−(3−cosθ)/8 − (−1)) dθ
. . . . . = ∫ [0 to 2π] 1/8 (cosθ + 5) dθ
. . . . . = 1/8 (sinθ + 5θ) | [0 to 2π] 
. . . . . = 1/8 [(0 + 10π) − (0 + 0)]
. . . . . = 5π/4

Comment: @Vince: The integral and the limits are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The region *between* the ellipse and the circle is what you are asked to investigate. So it's the ellipse minus the circle; an ellipse with a circular hole in int near its center.

Comment: b)

(x−1)²/9 + y²/8 = 1
8(x−1)² + 9y² = 72
8x² − 16x + 8 + 9y² = 72
9(x²+y²) − x² − 16x + 8 = 72
9(x²+y²) = x² + 16x + 64
9(x²+y²) = (x + 8)²

9r² = (r cosθ + 8)²
3r = r cosθ + 8
8 + r cosθ = 3r

a = 8, b = 3

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to compute the four apexes of the ellipse, since there might be some intersection in between. Argue instead as follows:

When $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ then $|x-1|\leq 2$ and therefore
$${(x-1)^2\over 9}+{y^2\over8}\leq {4\over9}+{1\over8}<1\ .$$

This shows that the unit circle is completely contained in the interior of the given ellipse.

Comment: I worked out the solution but not sure if it's right. Here it's can someone double check it for me please                               (x−1)²/9 + y²/8 = 1
8(x−1)² + 9y² = 72
8x² − 16x + 8 + 9y² = 72
9(x²+y²) − x² − 16x + 8 = 72
9(x²+y²) = x² + 16x + 64
9(x²+y²) = (x + 8)²

9r² = (r cosθ + 8)²
3r = r cosθ + 8
8 + r cosθ = 3r

a = 8, b = 3